# Clarifying callbacks with Plotly / Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, python-decorators, plotly-dash

I'm following their official documentation (https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks), but I'm very confused on callbacks.

I don't understand how there's no reference to `update_output_div()`, but it gets called, regardless of if you rename it something else. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reference to that function because it is just a name for a function. What you should consider is the decorator [`@app.callback()`](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/dev/dash/dash.py#L926).

To refresh ideas about decorators for functions and methods you can read [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually explained in all letters in the very page you linked to:

> 3. Whenever an input property changes, **the function that the callback decorator wraps will get called automatically**. Dash provides the function with the new value of the input property as an input argument and Dash updates the property of the output component with whatever was returned by the function.

As to how it works: Python functions are objects like any other (so you can pass them as arguments etc), and the

```
@decorator
def func():
    pass
```

thing is just syntactic sugar for

```
def func()
func = decorator(func)
```

so obviously the `app.callback` decorator is here used to store a reference to the decorated function so Dash can call it back later.